# PostgreSQL. Как экспортировать таблицу в csv формате?

Tags: python, postgresql, psql

У меня есть таблица "logs" в бд "data base". Второй день мучаюсь с тем, чтобы её выгрузить в csv формате.

Команды по типу `\Copy logs To 'D:/CSV.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;` не помогают. Всегда выскакивает ошибка "отношение logs не существует", при этом по пути, указанный в команде создаётся пустой csv файл.

[[image: Ошибки]

[[image: Таблица существует. Заполнена]

[[image: Создаётся]

Comment: А что покажет, если заменить `logs` на `"public"."logs"`?

Comment: Вы подключились к базе postgres а не к  `data base`. Попробуйте подключиться так `psql -U postgres -h localhost -d 'data base'`

Comment: @RabbanKeyak ОШИБКА:  отношение "public.logs" не существует

Comment: @godva так postgres это пользователь, владеющей бд, которая находится на локальном хосте

Comment: Решено. Оказывается, ко всему прочему, нужно было подключиться к определённой бд

Answer (score 1):

Решение проблемы:

Перед использованием команды

> \Copy logs To 'D:/CSV.csv' With CSV DELIMITER ',' HEADER;

Нужно было:

1. Войти в psql командой `psql -U имя_пользователя (по стандарту postgres)`
2. Следующим шагом вам нужно подключиться к базе данных, в которой лежит ваша таблица. В моём случае это `\connect "data base"`
3. И после вы сможете скопировать таблицу в csv формате командой выше.

Надеюсь, что всем попавшим новичкам в такую же беду этот ответ поможет.